# How to get a progress value provided by a BackgroundWorker?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

Is there something like this on `BackgroundWorker`? when a function ends in `DoWork` callback, I get it on `ProgressChanged` a value of this progress according with the functions are ending.

Code example:

```
bw.DoWork += (a,b) => {
  foo();
  baa();
  if(..) else {  }
};
```

when each statement ends, I get it on

```
  bw.ProgressChanged += (o, e) => {
                   MessageBox.Show(e.ProgressPercentage);
   };
```

I have three stataments, it should print three `Message.Show()`: 33,66,100

`33`% => `foo()` was executed.

`66`% => `baa()` was executed.

`100`% =>  `if(..) else {  }` the last statement was executed, done.

I could to call `.ReportProgress()` method inside each function/statement that run on `DoWork` callback event,but depending of statements numbers,this can be inviable.

I hope this is clear. And my apologies for my bad english.

Comment: Why is calling `ReportProgress` "inviable"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question; the answer is 'No, there is no way for the backgroundworker to automatically report it's progress'.

You'll have to explicitly make calls to  `.ReportProgress()`

```
bw.DoWork += (a,b) => {
  foo();
  worker.ReportProgress(33);
  baa();
  worker.ReportProgress(66);
  if(..) else {  }
};
```

You could get clever and do something like build a queue of Actions, call each action and call ReportProgress after each, if you are really dealing with a large number of method calls in your DoWork body.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a problem with the following approach?

```
bw.DoWork += (a,b) => {
  foo();
  bw.ReportProgress(33);
  baa();
  bw.ReportProgress(66);
  if(..) else {  }
  bw.ReportProgress(100);
};
```

I would only try and call `ReportProgress` inside of `foo` or `baa` if there was some compelling reason to (i.e. to increment from 33 to 66, a few percent at a time, inside of `foo`).